# Array not return properly

Tags: php, arrays, file-get-contents

Following code:

```
$names = file_get_contents('names.txt');
var_dump($names);
```

Is returning in var_dump:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'asd
dwqd
asfa
fewfw' (length=22)
```

Meanwhile, this returns correct way:

```
$test = array('tete','asdasd','yryr');
var_dump($test);
```

Result:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'tete' (length=4)
  1 => string 'asdasd' (length=6)
  2 => string 'yryr' (length=4)
```

So, the code block when I try to get names from file and make an array of them return an wrong format array. `names.txt` is built as following:

```
asd
dwqd
asfa
fewfw
```

Comment: Erm... `$names = array_map('trim',file("names.txt"));`, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you're not splitting the lines into an array, it's just reading the whole files as a block of text.

Use [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) with the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag. The flag says `Do not add newline at the end of each array element`, turning your multiple lines into single lines of an array.

Try:

```
$names = file('names.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
var_dump($names);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was knowing that I'm not splitting it correctly, but didn't know an good way to do this. Again, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You are just printing normal string from text file. You need to explode in to array.

Use,

```
$array = explode(" ",$names);
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: This would not work: 1. The values are not delimited by a space but a newline 2. Even if it works (documentation doesn't say, but it's _possible_ a space also splits a newline - not a safe assumption to mkae, though), it is possible to have a line with a space in it in the file which you shouldn't be splitting.

Answer (score 0):

Use `file()`:

```
$names = trim(file('names.txt'));
var_dump($names);
```